# Disable Popup blocker of android webview and iphone UIWebview

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c, webview, android-webview

In android, the default behavior when I open my webpage is that after login it opens the next page in a new window. But now when I open it in android webview, it does not open the next page. I google about it, and the cause seems to be the popup blocker. So, is there any simple way to disable the popup blocker in the android webview?

I have do the same thing objective C UIWebview.

Thanks

Comment: Will you explain, what you want to do actualy ??

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I had edit my question.

Comment: You mean you can go back from one page to another in default android browser but in your application while you go back then you come out from the webView right ?? is it like that or anything else ?

Comment: I means on default browser a particular link open new window. But when I do this in android webview it is not happening.